source the bash script with runArgs in .devcontainer.json
When I run the container, I normally used
docker run -it ${docker_image} /bin/sh -c ". /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh; ./a.out"

to source a bash script before running the executable. I would like to automatically source this script in the VS Code's dev container environment by adjusting the runArgs such as
"runArgs": [
   "/bin/sh -c '. /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh'",
],

Unfortunately that doesn't work. What is the way to set it correctly?
